# Cores fail when trying to add requestHandler in Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am new to Solr and am trying to add the [Suggest Search Component](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/suggester.html#adding-the-suggest-search-component) via the [Config API](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/configuration-guide/config-api.html).

My Solr 9.0.0 setup is as follows:

1. `bin/solr start -e cloud`  with _default config
2. Add the search component with a POST request to `http://localhost:8983/api/collections/collection_name/config`:

```
{
  "add-searchcomponent": {
    "name": "suggest",
    "class": "solr.SuggestComponent",
    "lookupImpl": "FuzzyLookupFactory",
    "dictionaryImpl": "DocumentDictionaryFactory",
    "field": "name",
    "suggestAnalyzerFieldType": "string",
    "buildOnStartup": "false"
  }
}
```

Until here everything is fine and I receive a responseHeader with status 0.

3. Add the request handler with a POST request to `http://localhost:8983/api/collections/collection_name/config`:

```
{
  "add-requesthandler": {
    "name": "/suggest",
    "class": "solr.SearchHandler",
    "defaults": {
      "suggest": "true",
      "rows": "10"
    },
    "components": "suggest"
  }
}
```

In step 3 I receive a responseHeader with status 500 and the following error message:

> 1 out of 2 the property overlay to be of version 4 within 30 seconds! Failed cores: [http://localhost:8983/solr/collection_name1_replica_n1/]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it. My error was not adding “components” in the add-requesthandler as an array.

original:

```
{
  "add-requesthandler": {
    "name": "/suggest",
    "class": "solr.SearchHandler",
    "defaults": {
      "suggest": "true",
      "rows": "10"
    },
    "components": "suggest"
  }
}
```

correct:

```
{
  "add-requesthandler": {
    "name": "/suggest",
    "class": "solr.SearchHandler",
    "defaults": {
      "suggest": "true",
      "rows": "10"
    },
    "components": [“suggest"]
  }
}
```